# Is it possible to convert DVI to DVI-D?

Tags: graphics-card, display, dvi

I'm buying a new graphics card which has DVI and mini HDMI interfaces. However my monitor is DVI-D and VGA.

Is it possible to convert a DVI cable to DVI-D so I can connect it to my monitor? Do I need a specific adapter or can I just connect a DVI cable into the DVI-D plug at the back of my monitor without any sort of converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a graphics card says that it has "DVI" it does not discern between DVI-I or DVI-D or DVI-A - rest assured, your card is capable of outputting DVI-D.

In other words, no adapter is needed, the Graphics card will work with your monitor.

Comment: Actually, this isn't 100% correct. Some computers may not have support for DVI-A. For example, some Macintosh computers will only output DVI-D on a DVI cable and I've seen laptops which don't support DVI-A on the DVI port and require use of VGA connector for analog video.

Comment: Did the DVI cable have a DVI-D or I pinout or a DVI-A pinout, I've had a Quicksilver G4 and a 2007 Macbook Pro that had full DVI ports and there were no issues working with DVI-A monitor connections as long as the DVI cable in use had a DVI-A pinout. Regardless, when a product says that it has DVI - they don't say specifically DVI-D, I, or A - it just says DVI.

Comment: As far as I know, the Apple DVI-A problem affects mini DisplayLink laptops which need to use adapters. My Acer Aspire 7720G laptop has a DVI port which has pin configuration such that it can only accent DVI-D cables.